# SSRS: details data should start from the same row as the group header

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I have been looking for this for days on google and still unsuccesful. I have a table which has the following data.

```
a|  b|  c|  1|

a|  b|  c|  2|

a|  b|  c|  3|

z|  y|  x|  2|

z|  y|  x|  3|

z|  y|  x|  5|
```

I have been Trying to find the ways so that When I get the report in SSRS the details result should start from the very row of the group. What I am getting is something like this.

[image]

But what I want is result to look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tablix with the following data arrangement.

[image]

It will preview the following tablix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, but creating a child group will cause problem with the interactive sorting. This will only sort on the parent group. There can be only one group , parent. That way you can sort with all the columns apart from the details.